# ROS Live Community Meeting February

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was participating in the meeting that was about Robot Description Formats.
I would like to ask the links that were shared in the chat. Because, I was using a phone and it is impossible to follow them.
Also, could you inform where I can listen the record again?! I have the language limitation of understanding the content in English completely.

Thank you for the meeting!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227605/ros-live-community-meeting-february/) by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2016-02-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2016-07-12**:
hey gorgeous...hhmm...I mean flawless...well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for listening!

We are preparing a post for a summary of the meeting, a link to the recording, and the notes (which will include links) to ROS Users and the ROS blog (http://www.ros.org/news/).

In the meantime, here is the link to the notes taken during the meeting:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rU9aipNMm0gdMqh9qQdBq0kz8nYCZXzsNu3IK1kNZXc/edit?usp=sharing

---

Originally posted by [jackie](https://answers.ros.org/users/23055/jackie/) with karma: 296 on 2016-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3